# Do I add quotes around my thoughts?

Tags: punctuation, quotes, quotation-marks

He staggered in, late as usual, his hair this way and his collar the other. His socks were as mismatched as were his principles. I thought to myself, here comes yet another disastrous sales meeting.

It seems to me too much to write :

> I thought to myself 'Here comes yet another disastrous sales meeting'.

The Authorised Version deliberately did away with punctuated speech, retaining only the capital to indicate the beginning of a quote but leaving out quotation marks.

Can I therefore do the same in common writing, for my thoughts ?

> I thought to myself, Here comes yet another disastrous sales meeting.

I cannot find another question on EL&U which covers this.

Comment: It’s a matter of style. Different publishers use different conventions.

Comment: Do you add quotes around your thoughts? Only you (at most) would know. Do you? (I wonder how you do that...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The Handbook of Good English](https://books.google.com/books?id=n0IJ8GcdJ6IC&pg=PA154) (slightly reformatted below) suggests the following:

> Direct quotations of thoughts
>
> Thoughts can be treated like other quotations and enclosed in
> quotation marks. They can also be italicized, without quotation marks.
> Both of these conventions are common. It is more common to dispense
> with both quotation marks and italics:
>
> - Johnson thought, Now why did I say that?
> - Now why did I say that? he brooded.

You can find plenty of examples of each in books:

- [Example with quotes](https://books.google.com/books?id=TvkzQHOfNFkC&pg=PT88&dq=%22she+thought%22.)
- [Example with italics](https://books.google.com/books?id=uaZpVBTT2Z4C&pg=PT42&dq=%22she+thought%22.)
- [Example with both quotes and italics](https://books.google.com/books?id=oRQSMgb2bFcC&pg=PT114&dq=%22he+thought%22.)
- [Example with neither quotes nor italics](https://books.google.com/books?id=DNbqTO6VhwEC&pg=PA135&dq=%22he+thought%22.)

Whatever you do, the important thing is to be consistent.

Comment: I wish I could persuade writers to use .oO( thought balloons ) for this!

Comment: @Will Crawford Suitable only for lofty aspirations.